# ANOVA for difference of means - is there a random effect due to population sampling?

Tags: anova, random-effects-model

I would like to know if a population sampling "random effect" applies in a very simple difference-of-means test.

**CASE 1:** A toy scenario to setup the question: suppose we want to compare the performance of athletes in a particular game/sport in the Olympic summer games, and see if those who are from the southern hemisphere (SH) have a different performance from those who are from the northern hemisphere (NH).

We have Olympic games data only from the past 80 years (20 games, one every 4 years) Say there are 10 athletes who compete in the particular game, so there are 200 total observations. Let's ignore the issue of unbalanced data and imagine that there are 100 observations of people from the Northern hemisphere, and 100 from the Southern hemisphere. No athlete performs more than once, so there is no nesting/grouping by athlete. We are not interested in a by-year grouping.

We use ANOVA to model the means of the NH/SH groups, expressed in R as something like

```
model = lm(Performance ~ Origin, data = Data)
```

where Origin is a two-level variable with values (NH, SH).

OK, now on to the question. We want to generalize this beyond Olympic athletes (maybe because Olympic contenders from the SH actually move to the NH to do training) to see if there is a more general southern/northern effect. Athletes from university teams will be used.

**CASE 2:** Here we sample 200 randomly chosen university athletes from the northern hemisphere, and obtain their performance in their most recent game. Similarly we also sample 200 observations from the southern hemisphere.

In Case 1, ***all*** the olympic athletes were used (from the particular time range where data was available).
In Case 2, the chosen athletes are a **subsample** of all university athletes. If the exact procedure was repeated, we would sample different athletes, and get different means as a result.

The question: is this difference between Cases 1,2, something that can be modeled as a random effect in Case 2? (and if so how can it be expressed in R?)